# Xerces library and Android SDK Build-tools 19.x

Tags: android

When I used Build-tools 18.x, project built successfully.
Now when I'm trying to build my project in Android Studio or Eclipse with 19.x it fails with the following message. How can I fix it?

```
Dx 1 error; aborting
Conversion to Dalvik format failed with error 1
```

Here is the entire console log.

```
[2014-04-18 17:46:07 - ARMRSS] Dx warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class
(org.apache.html.dom.SecuritySupport$1) that doesn't come with an
associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a
compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended
solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler
and without specifying any "-target" type options. The consequence of ignoring
this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly
indicate that it is *not* an inner class.
[2014-04-18 17:46:07 - ARMRSS] Dx warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class
(org.apache.html.dom.SecuritySupport$2) that doesn't come with an
associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a
compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended
solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler
and without specifying any "-target" type options. The consequence of ignoring
this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly
indicate that it is *not* an inner class.
[2014-04-18 17:46:07 - ARMRSS] Dx warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class
(org.apache.html.dom.SecuritySupport$3) that doesn't come with an
associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a
compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended
solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler
and without specifying any "-target" type options. The consequence of ignoring
this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly
indicate that it is *not* an inner class.
[2014-04-18 17:46:07 - ARMRSS] Dx warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class
(org.apache.html.dom.SecuritySupport$4) that doesn't come with an
associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a
compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended
solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler
and without specifying any "-target" type options. The consequence of ignoring
this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly
indicate that it is *not* an inner class.
[2014-04-18 17:46:07 - ARMRSS] Dx warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class
(org.apache.html.dom.SecuritySupport$5) that doesn't come with an
associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a
compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended
solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler
and without specifying any "-target" type options. The consequence of ignoring
this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly
indicate that it is *not* an inner class.
[2014-04-18 17:46:07 - ARMRSS] Dx warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class
(org.apache.html.dom.SecuritySupport$6) that doesn't come with an
associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a
compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended
solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler
and without specifying any "-target" type options. The consequence of ignoring
this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly
indicate that it is *not* an inner class.
[2014-04-18 17:46:07 - ARMRSS] Dx warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class
(org.apache.html.dom.SecuritySupport$7) that doesn't come with an
associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a
compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended
solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler
and without specifying any "-target" type options. The consequence of ignoring
this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly
indicate that it is *not* an inner class.
[2014-04-18 17:46:07 - ARMRSS] Dx warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class
(org.apache.html.dom.SecuritySupport$8) that doesn't come with an
associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a
compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended
solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler
and without specifying any "-target" type options. The consequence of ignoring
this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly
indicate that it is *not* an inner class.
[2014-04-18 17:46:07 - ARMRSS] Dx warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class
(org.apache.xerces.dom.CharacterDataImpl$1) that doesn't come with an
associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a
compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended
solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler
and without specifying any "-target" type options. The consequence of ignoring
this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly
indicate that it is *not* an inner class.
[2014-04-18 17:46:07 - ARMRSS] Dx warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class
(org.apache.xerces.dom.ParentNode$1) that doesn't come with an
associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a
compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended
solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler
and without specifying any "-target" type options. The consequence of ignoring
this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly
indicate that it is *not* an inner class.
[2014-04-18 17:46:07 - ARMRSS] Dx warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class
(org.apache.xerces.dom.SecuritySupport$1) that doesn't come with an
associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a
compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended
solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler
and without specifying any "-target" type options. The consequence of ignoring
this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly
indicate that it is *not* an inner class.
[2014-04-18 17:46:07 - ARMRSS] Dx warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class
(org.apache.xerces.dom.SecuritySupport$2) that doesn't come with an
associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a
compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended
solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler
and without specifying any "-target" type options. The consequence of ignoring
this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly
indicate that it is *not* an inner class.
[2014-04-18 17:46:07 - ARMRSS] Dx warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class
(org.apache.xerces.dom.SecuritySupport$3) that doesn't come with an
associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a
compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended
solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler
and without specifying any "-target" type options. The consequence of ignoring
this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly
indicate that it is *not* an inner class.
[2014-04-18 17:46:07 - ARMRSS] Dx warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class
(org.apache.xerces.dom.SecuritySupport$4) that doesn't come with an
associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a
compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended
solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler
and without specifying any "-target" type options. The consequence of ignoring
this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly
indicate that it is *not* an inner class.
[2014-04-18 17:46:07 - ARMRSS] Dx warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class
(org.apache.xerces.dom.SecuritySupport$5) that doesn't come with an
associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a
compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended
solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler
and without specifying any "-target" type options. The consequence of ignoring
this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly
indicate that it is *not* an inner class.
[2014-04-18 17:46:07 - ARMRSS] Dx warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class
(org.apache.xerces.dom.SecuritySupport$6) that doesn't come with an
associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a
compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended
solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler
and without specifying any "-target" type options. The consequence of ignoring
this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly
indicate that it is *not* an inner class.
[2014-04-18 17:46:07 - ARMRSS] Dx warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class
(org.apache.xerces.dom.SecuritySupport$7) that doesn't come with an
associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a
compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended
solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler
and without specifying any "-target" type options. The consequence of ignoring
this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly
indicate that it is *not* an inner class.
[2014-04-18 17:46:07 - ARMRSS] Dx warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class
(org.apache.xerces.dom.SecuritySupport$8) that doesn't come with an
associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a
compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended
solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler
and without specifying any "-target" type options. The consequence of ignoring
this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly
indicate that it is *not* an inner class.
[2014-04-18 17:46:07 - ARMRSS] Dx warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class
(org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLEntityManager$1) that doesn't come with an
associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a
compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended
solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler
and without specifying any "-target" type options. The consequence of ignoring
this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly
indicate that it is *not* an inner class.
[2014-04-18 17:46:07 - ARMRSS] Dx warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class
(org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLEntityScanner$1) that doesn't come with an
associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a
compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended
solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler
and without specifying any "-target" type options. The consequence of ignoring
this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly
indicate that it is *not* an inner class.
[2014-04-18 17:46:07 - ARMRSS] Dx warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class
(org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLErrorReporter$1) that doesn't come with an
associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a
compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended
solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler
and without specifying any "-target" type options. The consequence of ignoring
this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly
indicate that it is *not* an inner class.
[2014-04-18 17:46:07 - ARMRSS] Dx warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class
(org.apache.xerces.impl.dv.SecuritySupport$1) that doesn't come with an
associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a
compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended
solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler
and without specifying any "-target" type options. The consequence of ignoring
this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly
indicate that it is *not* an inner class.
[2014-04-18 17:46:07 - ARMRSS] Dx warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class
(org.apache.xerces.impl.dv.SecuritySupport$2) that doesn't come with an
associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a
compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended
solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler
and without specifying any "-target" type options. The consequence of ignoring
this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly
indicate that it is *not* an inner class.
[2014-04-18 17:46:07 - ARMRSS] Dx warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class
(org.apache.xerces.impl.dv.SecuritySupport$3) that doesn't come with an
associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a
compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended
solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler
and without specifying any "-target" type options. The consequence of ignoring
this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly
indicate that it is *not* an inner class.
[2014-04-18 17:46:07 - ARMRSS] Dx warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class
(org.apache.xerces.impl.dv.SecuritySupport$4) that doesn't come with an
associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a
compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended
solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler
and without specifying any "-target" type options. The consequence of ignoring
this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly
indicate that it is *not* an inner class.
[2014-04-18 17:46:07 - ARMRSS] Dx warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class
(org.apache.xerces.impl.dv.SecuritySupport$5) that doesn't come with an
associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a
compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended
solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler
and without specifying any "-target" type options. The consequence of ignoring
this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly
indicate that it is *not* an inner class.
[2014-04-18 17:46:07 - ARMRSS] Dx warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class
(org.apache.xerces.impl.dv.SecuritySupport$6) that doesn't come with an
associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a
compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended
solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler
and without specifying any "-target" type options. The consequence of ignoring
this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly
indicate that it is *not* an inner class.
[2014-04-18 17:46:07 - ARMRSS] Dx warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class
(org.apache.xerces.impl.dv.SecuritySupport$7) that doesn't come with an
associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a
compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended
solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler
and without specifying any "-target" type options. The consequence of ignoring
this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly
indicate that it is *not* an inner class.
[2014-04-18 17:46:07 - ARMRSS] Dx warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class
(org.apache.xerces.impl.dv.SecuritySupport$8) that doesn't come with an
associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a
compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended
solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler
and without specifying any "-target" type options. The consequence of ignoring
this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly
indicate that it is *not* an inner class.
[2014-04-18 17:46:07 - ARMRSS] Dx warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class
(org.apache.xerces.impl.dv.xs.XSSimpleTypeDecl$1) that doesn't come with an
associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a
compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended
solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler
and without specifying any "-target" type options. The consequence of ignoring
this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly
indicate that it is *not* an inner class.
[2014-04-18 17:46:07 - ARMRSS] Dx warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class
(org.apache.xerces.impl.dv.xs.XSSimpleTypeDecl$2) that doesn't come with an
associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a
compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended
solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler
and without specifying any "-target" type options. The consequence of ignoring
this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly
indicate that it is *not* an inner class.
[2014-04-18 17:46:07 - ARMRSS] Dx warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class
(org.apache.xerces.impl.dv.xs.XSSimpleTypeDecl$3) that doesn't come with an
associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a
compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended
solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler
and without specifying any "-target" type options. The consequence of ignoring
this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly
indicate that it is *not* an inner class.
[2014-04-18 17:46:07 - ARMRSS] Dx warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class
(org.apache.xerces.impl.dv.xs.XSSimpleTypeDecl$4) that doesn't come with an
associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a
compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended
solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler
and without specifying any "-target" type options. The consequence of ignoring
this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly
indicate that it is *not* an inner class.
[2014-04-18 17:46:07 - ARMRSS] Dx warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class
(org.apache.xerces.impl.xpath.XPath$1) that doesn't come with an
associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a
compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended
solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler
and without specifying any "-target" type options. The consequence of ignoring
this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly
indicate that it is *not* an inner class.
[2014-04-18 17:46:07 - ARMRSS] Dx 
UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
com.android.dx.cf.iface.ParseException: bad utf-8 byte a0 at offset 00000004
    at com.android.dx.cf.cst.ConstantPoolParser.parseUtf8(ConstantPoolParser.java:374)
    at com.android.dx.cf.cst.ConstantPoolParser.parse0(ConstantPoolParser.java:262)
    at com.android.dx.cf.cst.ConstantPoolParser.parse0(ConstantPoolParser.java:294)
    at com.android.dx.cf.cst.ConstantPoolParser.parse(ConstantPoolParser.java:150)
    at com.android.dx.cf.cst.ConstantPoolParser.parseIfNecessary(ConstantPoolParser.java:124)
    at com.android.dx.cf.cst.ConstantPoolParser.getPool(ConstantPoolParser.java:115)
    at com.android.dx.cf.direct.DirectClassFile.parse0(DirectClassFile.java:482)
    at com.android.dx.cf.direct.DirectClassFile.parse(DirectClassFile.java:406)
    at com.android.dx.cf.direct.DirectClassFile.parseToInterfacesIfNecessary(DirectClassFile.java:388)
    at com.android.dx.cf.direct.DirectClassFile.getMagic(DirectClassFile.java:251)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processClass(Main.java:665)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processFileBytes(Main.java:634)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.access$600(Main.java:78)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main$1.processFileBytes(Main.java:572)
    at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processArchive(ClassPathOpener.java:284)
    at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processOne(ClassPathOpener.java:166)
    at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.process(ClassPathOpener.java:144)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processOne(Main.java:596)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processAllFiles(Main.java:498)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMonoDex(Main.java:264)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:230)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.build.DexWrapper.run(DexWrapper.java:187)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.build.BuildHelper.executeDx(BuildHelper.java:786)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.build.builders.PostCompilerBuilder.build(PostCompilerBuilder.java:597)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager$2.run(BuildManager.java:726)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:199)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:321)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.build(BuildManager.java:396)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Project$1.run(Project.java:618)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Workspace.run(Workspace.java:2344)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Project.internalBuild(Project.java:597)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Project.build(Project.java:124)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.project.ProjectHelper.doFullIncrementalDebugBuild(ProjectHelper.java:1143)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.launch.LaunchConfigDelegate.launch(LaunchConfigDelegate.java:155)
    at org.eclipse.debug.internal.core.LaunchConfiguration.launch(LaunchConfiguration.java:855)
    at org.eclipse.debug.internal.core.LaunchConfiguration.launch(LaunchConfiguration.java:704)
    at org.eclipse.debug.internal.ui.DebugUIPlugin.buildAndLaunch(DebugUIPlugin.java:1047)
    at org.eclipse.debug.internal.ui.DebugUIPlugin$8.run(DebugUIPlugin.java:1251)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:53)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: bad utf-8 byte a0 at offset 00000004
    at com.android.dx.rop.cst.CstString.throwBadUtf8(CstString.java:171)
    at com.android.dx.rop.cst.CstString.utf8BytesToString(CstString.java:143)
    at com.android.dx.rop.cst.CstString.<init>(CstString.java:200)
    at com.android.dx.cf.cst.ConstantPoolParser.parseUtf8(ConstantPoolParser.java:371)
    ... 43 more
...while parsing cst 00bf at offset 000008dd
...while parsing cst 003c at offset 00000109
...while parsing org/apache/xerces/impl/xpath/regex/ParserForXMLSchema.class

[2014-04-18 17:46:07 - ARMRSS] Dx 1 error; aborting
[2014-04-18 17:46:07 - ARMRSS] Conversion to Dalvik format failed with error 1
```

Answer (score -1):

I am experiencing exactly the same issue.
What I have noticed, though, is that this problem only occurs when I build the debug .apk. That is, the release .apk is built with no such error. Funny...
You may give it a try, if you still have this issue in your agenga.